# Accessing array of classes

Tags: arrays

I am trying to create a 1d array that contains classes as its type. The following code is what have so far:

```
public class dog{
int x;
int y;
int health;
}

 Dog[] dog_properties = new Dog[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
Dog d = new Dog();
d.x = 2;
d.y = 3;
d.health = 10;
dog_properties[i] = d;
}
```

How do i access each property of dog from the array once it has been stored there? By this i mean i if want to iterate over the array later on how do i access d.x?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    int x = dog_properties[i].x;
}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Dog d = dog_properties[i];
    int x = d.x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the properties are public you can do:

```
for(int i; i < 4; i++){
  int x = dog_properties[i].x;
}
```